# What's the unit of RSS in psutil.Process.get_memory_info?

Tags: python, process

When I use `ps -o pid,rss -p 1`, I see the following:

```
PID RSS
  1 784
```

But when I query for `rss` with `psutil`, I get a different value:

```
>>> p = psutil.Process(1)
>>> print p.get_memory_info().rss
802816
```

Is it possible that `psutil` uses a different unit?
I can't find any related information in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Classes).

Comment: Link to new docs: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#psutil.Process.memory_info

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The output of ps is in kiloBytes. RSS (resident set size) from psutil is in bytes.

```
>>> 802816 / 784
1024
```

From `man ps`:

```
rss         RSS       resident set size, the non-swapped physical 
           memory that a task has used (in kiloBytes).  (alias rssize, rsz).
```

Comment: Technically that's kibibytes. A kilobyte is 1000 bytes but a kibibyte is 1024 bytes. Same analogous for mebibytes, gibibytes, and tebibytes.

Answer (score 6):

```
import os
import psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print(process.memory_info().rss)  # in bytes
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you need any more code to explain the difference?

Comment: i just mean the result displayed with this code is in bytes (not KB or any other unit). The proof is" assuming the result is in KB, the memory info displayed on my PC displayed is way larger than actually memory that my PC can have as whole. Additionally I visited several other sites and blogs and concluded that Bytes is correct unit.